# Alternative to dput(), cat() to save vector to global env

Tags: r, vector, range, cat, dput

I have several cases where I am trying to save a vector of elements to my global environment to be able to use for querying a database or other subsequent analyses.

As an example, I have a dataframe below, but **in reality my data consists of thousands of values**.

```
df:
example start   stop   range
set1    1       4180   1:4180
set2    460     499    460:499
set3    1       1127   1:1127
set4    1128    1622   1128:1622
set5    3741    3748   3741:3748
```

With this dataframe I want to capture every integer between start and stop, so I would like to use the range column to create a vector of every integer.

I have been using:

```
cat(paste0(df$range, collapse = ", "))
```

Which then prints to the console:

```
1:4180, 460:499, 1:1127, 1128:1622, 3741:3748
```

I have then been copy/pasting that output to save it as a vector in my global environment:

```
nums <- c(1:4180, 460:499, 1:1127, 1128:1622, 3741:3748)
```

Once I have this vector I can then do additional analyses such as:

```
> length(nums)
[1] 5850
> length(unique(nums))
[1] 4180
> summary(nums)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1     712    1443    1727    2726    4180
```

etc. etc.

Is there a simple way to skip the copy/paste step and save my desired formatting as a vector directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `Map` to get the sequence (`:`) between the corresponding 'start', 'stop' values and `unlist` the `list` of vectors to a single vector.

```
vec <- unlist(Map(`:`, df$start, df$stop))
```

---

Or if we want to use the 'range' column, then `eval`uate it

```
vec1 <- sapply(df$range, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that first option works great. I'm having issues with the second option because it's pulling the factor index from the range column, rather than the text itself and results in  `> length(unique(vec1))  
[1] 5`

Comment: @kholden in that case, just change it to `eval(parse(text  = as.character(x)))`

Comment: I also had to add an unlist() in there, but now both options work well, thanks so much!

Comment: @kholden yes, `sapply` returns a vector only if the length are same in the `list` elements.   For that reason, I always use `lapply` and then `unlist` (at least the behavior can be predetermined)